# javascript linking inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, html

So i have paid a coder to code to code me a side bar 
https://prnt.sc/siicq1

Has you can see there are buttons on the top but when im pressing the buttons it says it can not find the page

```
<ul class="menu-container horizontal-uniform width-100 margin-bottom-3 no-bot-border-rad">
<li class="menu-tab" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=follower_list&#39;, 0); return false;">Follower List</li>
<li class="menu-tab decorate-linethrough" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=social_feed&#39;, 0); return false;">Social Feed</li>
<li class="menu-tab" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=online_friends&#39;, 0); return false;">Friends Online</li>
<li class="menu-tab" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=friends_list&#39;, 0); return false;">Friends List</li>
<li class="menu-tab" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=ignore_list&#39;, 0); return false;">Ignore List</li>
<li class="menu-tab-end menu-tab-selected" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=online&#39;, 0); return false;">Online Members</li>
</ul>
<ul class="menu-container horizontal-uniform width-100 margin-bottom-3 no-border-rad">
```

```html
  
    <script>
    $($("#membersTab").contents().find('.add-section')).on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        $(this).parent().after("<li>"+$(this).parent().html()+"</li>");
    
    });
    
    
    </script>
    
    <script>
    $($("#menu-tab").contents().find('.add-section')).on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        $(this).parent().after("<li>"+$(this).parent().html()+"</li>");
    
    });
    
    
    </script>
```

Now i thought i would ask here to make sure im correct the javascript is just adding .html to end so for example

```
<li class="menu-tab" onClick="membersTab(&#39;view=follower_list&#39;, 0); return false;">Follower List</li>
```

would load follower_list.html ?

Comment: Inline handler are [terrible practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) nowadays. Use `addEventListener` instead. I'd highly recommend a better developer.

Comment: I just need to know the file names of what the script is looking for :) i mean were its linking to

Comment: looks like this is dead..

Comment: It's trying to call a `membersTab` function, so find where a `membersTab` function is declared